# How do I get the value (not check or unchecked) of a checkboxlist

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working on a winform app and am interating through a checkboxlist to see what's checked. If it's checked, i need to know what it's value member or value property is because I assigned it when I bound the checkbox list.

How can I get that?

Here's what I have now:

```
             for (int i = 0; i < clbIncludes.Items.Count; i++)

                if (clbIncludes.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
                {
                    //need the values of the checked checkbox here
                }");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    MyItem item = itemChecked as MyItem;

    if (item != null)
    {
       // use item...
    } 
}
```

MSDN [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx).