# Get unchecked values from CheckBoxList in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to update the unchecked values from `CheckBoxList` in button_click.
and not able to get the values of `CheckBoxList` unchecked items.

my code for populate chechboxlist is

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from hobbies";
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    ListItem item = new ListItem();
                    item.Text = sdr["Hobby"].ToString();
                    item.Value = sdr["HobbyId"].ToString();
                    item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IsSelected"]);
                    chkHobbies.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
           conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

i am using the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/410505/2376607

but it is for windows forms

please help how to get the unchecked values of `CheckBoxList`.

Comment: try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924147/how-to-get-values-of-selected-items-in-checkboxlist-with-foreach-in-asp-net-c

Comment: @Kumar this is for selected values i want to get Unselected values :(

Comment: You can use Hitesh answer.

Comment: @Gitz What's the big deal in that? Instead of using `item.Selected` just use `!item.Selected`(note the not symbol before item) in the linked answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below sample of code :-

```
        string chkboxlistValue = "";
        string uncheckedId = "";
        foreach (ListItem val in chkbxId.Items)
        {
            if (val.Selected)
            {
                chkboxlistValue += val.Value + " ";
            }
            else
            {
                 uncheckedId += val.Value + ",";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Once again saying that pleasure is all mine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (ListItem item in chkHobbies.Items)
{
   if (item.Selected == false)
   {
      // your code here
   }
}
```